# How to hide an input field of type search in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, search, mobile, input, hide

Okay, so I have two search input fields, like so:
[image: search fields]

I want to hide the 2nd/bottom one initially, but setting the input tag in html to *display: none*, the result is as such:

```
<input id="start" type="search" value="" placeholder="From">
<input id="end" type="search" value="" placeholder="To" style="display: none;">
```

gives:[image]

And I can't hide the element dynamically using jQuery on $(document).ready() as these inputs are on a separate jQM page, which isn't "rendered" yet (in termns of styling jqm does) - so something like $('#end').parent().hide() will hide the parent of both search bars.

As far as I can see, my options are creating that 2nd search form dynamically when needed or if there's a way to intterupt/add to jQM page rendering routine. There must/should be a better way, but I've had no luck finding it!

Suggestions welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

Right, so once again I eventually found the answer after quite a lot of googling and searching, the solution is to bind to an event jqm calls just before it makes the page visible (after it has applied it's mark-up):

```
$( '#mypage' ).on( 'pagebeforeshow',function(event){
    $("#end").parent().hide(); //hide the newly jqm-created div around my input
});
```

This gave the expected behaviour, it's might not be the best approach (with the parent()), but it's the gist of it.

I won't accept this as the official answer, in case someone comes up with a better way.